# XCache - where is serious documentation?

Tags: php, performance, caching, xcache

i'm trying to studying XCache but is very difficult to get complete documentation (or also lazy documentation like apc docs).

For example i'd like to know difference beetwen

```
xcache_list(0, 0);
```

and

```
xcache_list(1, 0);
```

Someone can helps me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, one fetches stored variables, the other fetches stored PHP pages (OPCODE cached pages):

The better use would be to use the constants:

```
xcache_list(XC_TYPE_VAR, 0)
```

and

```
xcache_list(XC_TYPE_PHP, 0)
```

As far as the docs, I haven't found anything on that function...

Comment: I suppose that the second argument is the slot number.